# kubernetes on minikube can't output to file

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, filesystems, devops, mount

I am using minikube on Ubuntu 18 and running a kubernetes job that should simply mount a dir and output something to a file using this yaml file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi13
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["/bin/echo"]
        args: ["1 >> /data/text12.txt"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            path: /home/user/data
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 1
```

It runs fine and gives this output in the dashboard

> 1 >> /data/shai12.txt

But writes nothing to the file (I try to read it on the host after the run is completed but nothing happens)

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your job should like like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi13
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: [ "sh", "-c"]
        args: ["echo 1 >> /data/text12.txt"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp/data
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 1
```

In your case you pass whole `1 >> /data/text12.txt` to echo command and as results it prints `1 >> /data/text12.txt` what you can check in job logs.

`hostPath` creates directory `/data`, so this is why you found it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I managed to connect to the pod and exec and inspect, seems that I write to the directory /data but this does not effect the hostpath i entered, how come? Even when mounting the host's /tmp/data it does not take effect and nothing happens in the host's file system while it's all fine in the pod fs

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to hostPath?

Comment: I am running minikube from the same user, and I changed the permissions to 777, so seems like permissions are not the issue here

Comment: I think this is the issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2