# kubernetes minikube not working with mount

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, filesystems, mount, minikube

I am using kubernetes with minikube and trying to create a mount on my machine, see [original SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372258/kubernetes-on-minikube-cant-output-to-file)

Someone pointed out [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2) github issue stating that hostPath mount on minikube is not working and suggested [this](http://pietervogelaar.nl/minikube-nfs-mounts) fix.

When I try to implement the fix and starting minikibe with the following command:

```
minikube start --mount --mount-string /home/user/data:/data
```

I suddenly cannot use

```
minikube dashboard
```

because I get this error (about a few tens of times):

> Temporary Error: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: Get
>   https://192.168.39.73:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard?timeout=1m0s:
>   dial tcp 192.168.39.73:8443: connect: connection refused

When I start minikube with

```
minikube start
```

The dashboard is working perfectly.

Comment: Could you please show us the error message you mentioned?

Comment: @OhHiMark added it as an edit

Comment: This page is better than the official minikube documents, ridiculous. I couldn't find anywhere at all that I needed --mount too and not just --mount-string /dir:/dir

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider:

1. Check if you have the dashboard addon enabled:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
kubectl describe pod <dashboard-addon-name> -n kube-system
```

ALSO

```
minikube addons list
```

Look for this:

```
...
- dashboard: enabled
...
```

To enable execute: `minikube addons enable dashboard`

2. There might be some issue with the versions due to the changes you made. Try to execute:

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start
```

before you hit:

```
minikube start --mount --mount-string /home/user/data:/data
```

3. Minikube needs dome time to get the pods ready. Try to simply wait a few minutes longer before trying to execute: `minikube dashboard`.
   Also you can check it with kubectl `get pods --all-namespaces`
4. Check your proxy configuration. You might need to add the minikube ip to the `no_proxy` env variable:

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,$(minikube ip)
```

5. If nothing helps you'll need to dig deeper. Start from the logs:

```
minikube dashboard --logtostderr --v=2
```

Please let me know if that helped.